# Textview cannot be resolved or is not a field - simple SQL database

Tags: java, android, sql

```
package com.example.checkoilforvectra;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

TextView imported.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
[...]
```

Here I have error - textView1 generates error. In example code I found on polish website author uses textView1 without error.

Comment: Can you share the layout xml file? Are you sure you set the name correctly there? Share the link of website, we can look at the code at least.

Comment: You need to add the textView1 into your layout file - xml

Comment: Do you have any TextView in your layout file which has `android:id="@+id/textView1"`? And are you sure you don't have it on a Fragment layout file, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the "activity_main" you need to have a TextView with the ID textView1, if you don't have one, create it :) , here is an example for a code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="David" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have initialized textView1 in activity_main xml file using `android:id="@+id/textView1"`

It must look like similar to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"   />    
</LinearLayout>
```